# What's this minor mode -- indicating recent change in left margin

Tags: emacs

[image]
This is the emacs init file from https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/, does anyone knows what's the package make the highlight of recent changes in left margin? Thanks.

Also, this emacs profile has a function, when the cursor stays on a word (goto-char in the figure) for around 3 seconds, all of its other occurrence in the buffer are highlighted as well. Please also let me know what's the packages achieving that.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Recursively bisect the init file to determine the cause. You can comment-out a region of code using `comment-region`. You should be able to find the answer to this yourself, without just throwing out a giant sack of code and asking "*What is it?*". Too broad. Ask Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but these are likely matches since I found both on the list of packages that are installed with the config (*elpa* folder).

- The highlight after 3 seconds is a feature provided by the **highlight-symbol** package, [available through Melpa](http://melpa.org/#/highlight-symbol). You can customise the amount of time it requires to highlight the symbol with the `highlight-symbol-idle-delay` variable.
- The other is **diff-hl**, which doesn't highlight recently changes, rather it highlight lines that are *uncommited*, if the file is under a particular version system (git, most likely). [Also available on melpa](http://melpa.org/#/diff-hl)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is the [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) mode. The mode highlights uncommitted changes in the current file on the margin or the fringe. It is included in the config you linked to: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-vc.el.